# How can I make a subdomain which points to another server?

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, serve

I use WHM and cPanle on my server. Here is my domain which works as well:

```
pronexo.net // points to 46.165.242.228
```

Now I want to make a subdomain which points to another server. So it should be like this:

```
mag.pronexo.net // should point to 51.254.92.146
```

How can I do that?

---

What I have done:

Editing my current dns zone:

[image]

And adding a new A record which points to that new ip:

[image]

But when I open this: `mag.pronexo.net`, it will be redirect to `http://mag.pronexo.net/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to create a subdomain Martin.

I am able to successfully load your subdomain at http://mag.pronexo.net/ and making a quick DNS lookup I see that it resolves from 51.254.92.146

The cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi output that you're seeing is most likely due to cache - try clearing your browser's cache and access the site again.